Can Eigenvector be a $n\times n$ matrix
We always hear about eigen vector $X$ is such that $AX=\lambda X$ where $X$ is $n\times 1$ vector. But my doubt is can $X$ be a $n\times n$ matrix?
Note: $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix
New Doubt Related to previous:
Also we have $(A-\lambda I)X=0$ and after taking determinant both side we get $|A-\lambda I||x|=0$ we have $|A-\lambda I|=0$. Is it becuase of $|X|$ can not be zero since it is column matrix and we can not find determinant of column matrix?

The eigenvectors of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ must be vectors in the usual sense, which are typically regarded as $n \times 1$ matrices. A linear operator over the set of $n \times n$ matrices, however, would indeed have $n \times n$ matrices as its "eigenvectors".

An eigenvector (one word) is a vector. An $n\times n$ matrix is not a vector if $n>1.$ Since there are determinants only for square matrices, $|X|$ doesn't mean anything when $X$ is a vector.

@ThomasAndrews I got about $|X|\neq 0$ because it is column matrix. But in answer provided by Koren Parkhov $X$ can be $n\times n$ vector

But $|AX|\neq |A||X|$ when $|A|$ is a determinant and $|AX|$ and $|X|$ are vector lengths. @mathophile

@But why People say $|A-\lambda I|=0$ if we cannnot apply determinant both side?

There is no $n\times n$ vector. It is not a vector, period. We can certainly find solutions matrices $X,\lambda$ to $AX=\lambda X$ which are $n\times m$ matrices, but they are not vectors, and certainly not eigenvectors.

$|A-\lambda I|=0$ because otherwise  $A-\lambda I$ has an inverse, and therefore, the only vector $X$ such that $(A-\lambda I)X=0$ is $X=0.$

And Koren is confused to call what he say an eigenvector. They later clarify it is a different concept, and eigenmatrix, an extension concept of an eigenvector. $X$ is not an eigenvector of,$A.$

In the end, such a matrix is really just a matrix with columns that are all eigenvectors (or zero) for the same eigenvalue. Basically, the columns come from one eigenspace for $A.$ Unless $A$ has only one eigenvalue, an eigenspace is dimension $<n,$ so any $n\times n$ "eigenmatrix" $X$ has $\det(X)=0.$ And you get eigenmatrices of dimension $n\times m$ for any $m.$ You get the same condition - all the columns must be elements of the eigenspace for one eigenvalue.

So the more key concept is the "eigenspace" of an eigenvalue. This is a real term, whereas I'm not sure if eigenmatrix is ever actually used.

In the end, you really need to talk about vector spaces and linear transformations. In general, if $V$ is a vector s-ace, and $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation, then an eigenvector of $T$ is a non-zero vector $v\in V$ such that... The concept of vectors and matrices correspond to vectors and linear transformations more generally, and a linear transformation is not a member of the vector,space, even if $T$ is a member of another vector space. So it is matter of being different types. They feel more related when looking a matrices, but matrices are only one type of linear transformation.

This is also why we tend to use lower case for vectors, sometimes bolder or with a vector symbol on top. It is to emphasize that it,is a different type of thing, even if we can treat a vector as a $n\times 1$ matrix

Yes, there is some sense in which an $n\times n$ matrix can be a "eigenvector". consider the map $T:\Bbb R ^ {n^2} \to \Bbb R ^ {n^2}$ defined by $T(X) = AX$. this is a linear map (check this!), therefore there exist some $n^2 \times n^2 $  matrix that represents $T$ in the standard base (think which matrix that would be, in terms of $A$).In that sense, "eigenmatrices" of $A$ would be just the eigenvectors of $T$

Importantly, these are the eigenvectors of $T$, not the eigenvectors (or eigenmatrices) of $A$. Referring to the eigenvectors of $A$ specifically means that we are interpreting $A$ as an operator in the usual fashion

This is not an eigenvector of $A,$ it is an eigenvector of $T.$
